# What's the equivalent for eclipse's ALT+UP/DOWN (move line) in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

In Eclipse, selecting a line and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> will move the line up and down, a quick way to avoid copy&paste.
Is there an equivalent in Visual Studio?

Comment: I wanted to know how to do this in eclipse now I know.

Comment: Note that in VS 2013+  this shortcut is now supported

Answer (score 158, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2013 and later, this functionality is built in. ALT + UP/DOWN will move a line up or down.

If you need this functionality in VS2012 (works with VS2010 too), take a look at the [MoveLine Visual Studio Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b3ee08dc-a28f-4aec-9efa-69215ab5ee52) or the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) suite.

Comment: Unbelievable that you need a plugin for this

Comment: how about child element when you select a tag ? for example I have selected a div tag and I want to move up all child element , instead of selecting by mouse .

Comment: If you want to rebind it, the name of the command is "Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp", under Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 worked out of the box!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, I installed ReSharper which screwed up some of my VS shortcuts, including this one. What's the name of the command or the way to reset this in VS2017?

Comment: @Shimmy you actually have a better option with Ctrl + Shift + Alt + Direction keys. You can move it anywhere.

Answer (score 92):

ReSharper's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> is even more powerful - when on the beginning of the line, it will move the entire line, but can also be used to move entire methods, change the order of parameters, etc.

Comment: Also doesn't work if R# thinks the current line is part of a larger construct.  E.g., try moving a `using` statement from the top of a file a few lines down to be inside the `namespace` declaration.  When the line containing the `using` is on the line below the `namespace` declaration, R# will combine them and the next call to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>&darr;</kbd> will move both the `namespace` and the `using` line all the way to the end of the former `namespace` code block.

Comment: Also doesn't seem to work to move lines across method boundaries.

Answer (score 35):

For me in Visual Studio 2019 it comes default closed.

For open it:

Tools -> Options -> Keyboard then select **Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp**, click "Press shortcut keys" input and press Alt + Up (or whatever you want for it). And the other one is **Edit.MoveSelectedLinesDown**, click "Press shortcut keys" input and press Alt + Down (or whatever you want for it).

Comment: I also found that these had no default key-binding in VS 2019

Comment: Alt+Up and Alt+Down are already bound to `Format.SpaceDown`, though I don't even know what that does. You think I can rebind it?

Comment: @IneffaWolf, anyway, bindings `Format.SpaceDown` and `Format.SpaceUp` can be executable within VC Dialog Editor (at least in VS2019 it is so). If you assign the same key bindings to `Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp/Down` but only for C# Editor, for example, I believe there won't be any conflict.

Answer (score 5):

This is now working out of the box with Visual Studio 2013, same way as in Eclipse.

Comment: Not quite the same, it doesn't correct the indentation

Comment: @Sentry
ctrl+k,D

Answer (score 5):

[image]

For Visual Studio 2013:
Tools -> Options -> Keyboard then select Edit.MoveSelectedLinesDown, click "Press shortcut keys" input and press Alt + Down. You also have to select the scope of the shortcut to be within "Text Editor".

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2013 and later, you can move lines up and down using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>. Unfortunately this will not adjust the indentation if you move between blocks, as of today only ReSharper (and all other IDE's by Jetbrains including Rider) can help you with that.

To move entire blocks of code around you can move the cursor to its head and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> twice fast to collapse it, and then use the command above to move it around.

[Here is a neat reference to all default keyboard shortcuts](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/) in different versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

With the VSCommands extension, you have exactly that keyboard shortcut. And, by the way, a Stack OVerflow notification toolbar :)