# Visual studio shortcut keys equivalent to eclipse shortcut keys

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I use both eclipse and visual studio (2008 right now) a lot. But there are some shortcut keys from eclipse that I really miss in Visual Studio that I haven't been able to locate. Does anyone know if these exists in Visual Studio?

**Being able to search in your open window tabs** - this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in eclipse I think? I know you can navigate, but not search.

**open type

  open type heirarchy

  open resource

move selected lines up or down (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>)

move to last edited line** (NOT <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> in VS and not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, which only works if you're in the same file?)

If they don't exist, anyone got a good resource on how you can program shortcuts yourself for VS?

Answer (score 3):

Just published new extension for Visual Studio:
[Meet IntelliCommand (Visual Studio 2010/2012 extension)](https://www.outcoldman.com/en/blog/show/326)

Comment: It is open sourced, you can try to fix it https://github.com/intellicommand/intellicommand, I have not used VS for a while, so not in the interest of maintaining it.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you for the moving of selected lines: [Visual Studio: hotkeys to move line up/down and move through recent changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526715/whats-the-equivalent-for-eclipses-altup-down-move-line-in-visual-studio)

Still searching on the others.

Comment: Moving lines with Alt is built-in since VS13 now.

Answer (score 1):

There is an "AsEclipse" plugin that should provide most functionality:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/99ede732-544c-4f3b-8e38-49e4b8395075

Comment: Does not work with VS 2015. The add-in author mentioned that he would convert it to be compatible with 2015 but I could not find any version newer than 3.0 :-(

Answer (score 1):

I am a first time user of VS.  **Open Resource** and **Open Type** look to be pretty well covered by Search in Solution Explorer, which is accessed using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Go to Settings keymaps and search for eclipse.
If you install Eclipse Keymap from Alphabot Security plugin in VS Code.
It has most of the shortcut from eclipse.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alphabotsec.vscode-eclipse-keybindings

Comment: This is for vs code not vs

Answer (score 0):

install telerik justcode... it has all shortcuts you just need to change them to be like in eclipse ... works like a charm after 15mins

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if following are VS or ReSharper shortcuts:
**open type heirarchy:** `Ctrl+E, Ctrl+H`
**move selected lines up or down:** `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT`

Answer (score 0):

To get eclipse like shortcuts in vscode:
Please go to:
**Ctrl+Shift+p** and type **java: Overview**
open overview using enter
there is option under Key Bindings
**Use Eclipse Key Bindings**
just click it.
and you will get all eclipse shortcuts in vscode

Answer (score 0):

Please check out:

- [DenGladkikh.IntelliCommand](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DenGladkikh.IntelliCommand) for Visual Studio 2017 and lower
- [LokeshGovindu.IntelliCommand](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LokeshGovindu.IntelliCommand) extension for Visual Studio 2022.