# Can we paste lines into visual studio "without carriage return"?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Lets say we have these lines in the editor

```
int a = 10;
print(a,b);
string b = "hello";
```

So what i would like to do is.. shift the 3rd line to the 2nd position similar to

```
int a = 10;
string b = "hello";
print(a,b);
```

I use ctrl+x or Shift + del to cut the line to the clipboard. 
But on pasting the line at 2nd position i get

```
int a = 10;
string b = "hello";

print(a,b);
```

The extra blank line at the 3rd line. is there any way to paste without that 3rd blank line. or for the matter an easier way to move and cut and paste lines. ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the equivalent for eclipse's ALT+UP/DOWN (move line) in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526715/whats-the-equivalent-for-eclipses-altup-down-move-line-in-visual-studio)

Comment: ^-- Marked as duplicate of much more popular/current answer, as the ones here from 2011 are outdated.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> swaps the current line with the line below it. So you'd put the caret (or cursor) on the second line, then use that keyboard shortcut to swap it with the third line.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the answer!. 
i just stumbled on to a easier method and more flexible. 
With a Addon - Pro tools 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef

we can now use Alt + Arrow keys to move the lines up or down.